# Resharper 8 and vendor prefixes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css, resharper-8.0

I use `Resharper 8`

I have a css stylesheet file which has this class :

```
.textShadow
{
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #5b5b5b;
}
```

When I hover it there is a suggestion (R#8 suggestion )
[image]

so when I click on it it says :

[image]

And so ,it added the vendor prefix :

[image]

But as far as I know , **there is no** `-ms-text-shadow` prefix.

Strange, but when I hover on the new added line , R#8 **does** say :

[image]

I don't understand , if R#8 knows that there is no such vendor prefix , why does he suggests it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 has a lot of knowledge about CSS 3. The information is stored in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\1033\schemas\CSS`. My guess is that the quick-fix to introduce `-ms-text-shadow` is based on ReSharper's own schema for CSS 3. However, the Visual Studio schema  (in `css-module-text.xml`) does not have a definition for `-ms-text-shadow` and this could be the source of the ReSharper inspection.

If that is true ReSharper has two ways of inspecting CSS 3, one based on a ReSharper schema and another based on Visual Studio schema. That is a possible explanation of the unexpected behavior you experience.

It is my understanding that if you install Web Essentials in Visual Studio 2012 it will automatically update the CSS 3 schema files from the information located at [Mads Kristensen's Real World Validator](http://realworldvalidator.com/css/module).

Comment: Martin thanks! (I will add the validator to my tool which ive built.  the JS one) p.s. i use vs2010 and not 2012...(at work..)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's a r# bug. I always use this web site to check compability and there's no text-shadow for IE until version 10:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-textshadow

but you could get the same result with this (in IE 9):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6900705/1384539

Comment: Thanks.I have a better tool to check http://jsbin.com/axaluq/40?q=text-shadow ...:-) ( checks both mdn and caniuse..) I built it myself cuz i alwasy check compatibility stuff :-)

Comment: nice to know that @RoyiNamir!